# how to login and get the redirected page using cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to use cURL and SimpleHtmlDom to post a 13-digit value and pull some data from this site :
http://www.hcad.org/records/Real.asp?search=acct

After posting a 13-digit value i want to get this redirected page : 
http://www.hcad.org/records/details.asp?crypt=%94%9A%B0%94%BFg%85%8E%84%82pg%8El%88tXt%5FW%9E%99%A2%D3%89%95%C2e%7CU%8A%7D%86%C0%AB%A8%AD%86%5E&bld=1&tab=

on which i will apply simplehtmldom to parse some data

i have searched some site to make this code snippet

```
<?php
$urltopost = "http://www.hcad.org/records/Real.asp?search=acct";
$datapost = array(
"searchval" => "1158830010007",
);
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $returndata;
?>
```

but its not providing me the redirected page i want .
what should i do now to do it correctly ?? waiting for any kind of help .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option for the curl to follow a redirect or it just returns the page data (if any) without redirecting.

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
```

**Edit**: I have looked at the source code on the page, you should modify your code accordingly:

```
$urltopost = "http://www.hcad.org/records/SelectRecord.asp";
$datapost = "searchval=1158830010007&TaxYear=2011&searchtype=strap";
```

You should have been posting to the page that the form submits to (see above `$urltopost`). Also, you should use a query string as your post data.

Comment: here is the edited code : http://codepad.org/gO9FMOH6 and here is the output : http://maruf10.tk/pulldata/pulldata.php . still not redirecting my desired page . what should i do now ?

Comment: its showing this error "Please do not use bookmarks within our site or type in the URL for specific search requests.
Instead, use the search boxes provided within the web page.
Please navigate back to the home page and start your search again."     i really need a complete tutorial on scrapping which covers all this pitfalls